# Is there a way calculate the ending position of an element before css transform matrix is applied?

Tags: javascript, css, algorithm, matrix, transform

I need to figure the ending bounding rect of an element before the css `transform: matrix()` transformation is applied. I have no idea really where to start and can't find any good articles addressing this.

So given you have the original position of the element with `getBoundingClientRect()` is there a reliable way to find the ending position if you have the matrix that is supposed to be applied.

I have built a scroll controller and I am trying to map the elements progress through the screen but I need the starting and ending position of the element. So I would need the position of the element after the css transformation is applied to figure out when the element has left the screen. Right now i am just applying the matrix and then running `getBoundingClientRect()` again. But this seems a bit hacky.

So given you have the original and ending matrix. And then you run the `getBoundingClientRect()` on the element to find its position. Is there a mathematical way to calculate the new bounding rect?

So for this example we will just use a 6 value matrix. But it would be nice to apply it to a full 16 value matrix as well:

```
const boundingRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
const startingMatrix = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0];
const endingMatrix = [2, 1, -1, 2, 200, 400];

// Now calculate the new bounding rect of element after ending matrix is applied.
```

I have tried the following based on this article https://dev.opera.com/articles/understanding-the-css-transforms-matrix/ recommended by the comments below. There is something that I obviously am missing or dont understand. Here is my attempt:

```js
const applyToPoint = (matrix, point) => {
  const multiplied = [
    matrix[0] * point[0],
    matrix[1] * point[1],
    matrix[2] * point[0],
    matrix[3] * point[1],
    matrix[4] * point[0],
    matrix[5] * point[1]
  ]

  const result = [
    multiplied[0] + multiplied[2] + multiplied[4],
    multiplied[1] + multiplied[3] + multiplied[5]
  ]

  return result
}

const box = document.querySelector('.box')

const startingMatrix = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
box.style.transform = `matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)`
const startingRect = box.getBoundingClientRect()

const endingMatrix = [2, 1, -1, 2, 200, 400]
box.style.transform = `matrix(2,1,-1,2,200,400)`
const endingRect = box.getBoundingClientRect()

const newPoint = applyToPoint(endingMatrix, [startingRect.x, startingRect.y])

console.log(newPoint, endingRect)
```

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

I also tried :

```
const applyToPoint = (matrix, point) => [
  matrix[0] * point[0] + matrix[2] * point[1] + matrix[4],
  matrix[1] * point[0] + matrix[3] * point[1] + matrix[5]
]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Or pointers in the right direction.

Comment: You can find a guide here: https://dev.opera.com/articles/understanding-the-css-transforms-matrix/

Comment: Eventually, I'll translate it to your use case later today

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here.  It seems simple enough.  Multiply the four corners of your bounding box by the 2x2 transform matrix, add the `tx` and `ty` translations to each point, and then take the minimum and maximum `x` and `y` values among these to find the new bounding box.  Is that not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have to simply multiply the matrix (you can do just the 2 x 2 version, and then add the translation variables.)  But as mentioned by Olivier, you need to first translate the coordinates, and then translate them back.  This is easy enough by just calculating the center.

I would write this as a function from a rectangle and matrix (as a flat array of the six variables used for the CSS transforms) into another rectangle, either a simple `{left, right, top, bottom}` rectangle or if you want, a DomRect.

You can see it in this snippet (easier to see if you expand it with the "full page" link):

```js
const transformRect = (rect, matrix) => {
  const {left, top, right, bottom} = rect
  const [a, b, c, d, tx, ty] = matrix
  const dx =  (left + right) / 2, dy = (top + bottom) / 2
  const newCorners = [[left, top], [right, top], [right, bottom], [left, bottom]]
    .map (([x, y]) => [
      a * (x - dx) + c * (y - dy) + tx + dx, 
      b * (x - dx) + d * (y - dy) + ty + dy
    ])
  const _left = Math .min (... newCorners .map (p => p [0]))
  const _right = Math .max (... newCorners .map (p => p [0]))
  const _top = Math .min (... newCorners .map (p => p [1]))
  const _bottom = Math .max (... newCorners .map (p => p [1]))

  return DOMRect.fromRect (
    {x: _left, y: _top, width: _right - _left, height: _bottom - _top}
  ) // or just
 // return {x: _left, y: _top, width: _right - _left, height: _bottom - _top}
}

const div = document .getElementById ('d2') 
const rect = div.getBoundingClientRect()
console .log ('Before:' , rect)

const matrix = [2, 1, -1, 2, 200, 400]
div.style.transform = `matrix(${matrix .join (', ')})`

console .log ('After:', transformRect (rect, matrix))
```

```css
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
#d1 {
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8;
  left: 8;
}
```

```html
<div id="d1" class="box">shadow</div>
<div id="d2" class="box">content</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you're mixing two different coordinate systems:

- The client system (used by `getBoundingClientRect()`)
- The local system (used by `transform`)

As stated in the [linked article](https://dev.opera.com/articles/understanding-the-css-transforms-matrix/#coordinates),
the local system's origin is the element's center:

> When a transform is applied to an object, it creates a local coordinate system. By default, the origin —
> the (0,0) point — of the local coordinate system lies at the object's center

Let's call `[xc, yc]` the element's center.

To transform a point (expressed in the client system), you need to do the following:

- Convert the coordinates from client to local system (by subtracting `xc` and `yc`)
- Apply the transform matrix
- Convert the resulting coordinates back from local to client (by adding `xc` and `yc`)

Here is a code that transforms the 4 box corners and computes the associated bounding box:

```js
var matrix = [2, 1, -1, 2, 200, 400];

var box = document.querySelector('.box');
var startingRect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
var xc = startingRect.left + startingRect.width/2;
var yc = startingRect.top + startingRect.height/2;

const applyMatrix = (matrix, point) => [
  matrix[0] * point[0] + matrix[2] * point[1] + matrix[4],
  matrix[1] * point[0] + matrix[3] * point[1] + matrix[5]
];
const clientToLocal = (point) => [point[0] - xc, point[1] - yc];
const localToClient = (point) => [point[0] + xc, point[1] + yc];
const transformPoint = (point) => localToClient(applyMatrix(matrix, clientToLocal(point)));

function getBoundingBox(pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4)
{
    var x1 = Math.min(pt1[0], pt2[0], pt3[0], pt4[0]);
    var y1 = Math.min(pt1[1], pt2[1], pt3[1], pt4[1]);
    var x2 = Math.max(pt1[0], pt2[0], pt3[0], pt4[0]);
    var y2 = Math.max(pt1[1], pt2[1], pt3[1], pt4[1]);
    return {x: x1, y: y1, width: x2 - x1, height: y2 - y1};
}

var topLeft = [startingRect.left, startingRect.top];
var topRight = [startingRect.right, startingRect.top];
var bottomLeft = [startingRect.left, startingRect.bottom];
var bottomRight = [startingRect.right, startingRect.bottom];
var transformedBox = getBoundingBox(transformPoint(topLeft), transformPoint(topRight), transformPoint(bottomLeft), transformPoint(bottomRight));
console.log(transformedBox);

box.style.transform = 'matrix('+matrix.join()+')';
var endingRect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(endingRect);
```

Output:

```
{x: 158, y: 400, width: 150, height: 150}
DOMRect {x: 158, y: 400, width: 150, height: 150, top: 400, …}
```

Answer (score -1):

> ...to figure out when the element has left the screen.

If you want to do something when element enters or exits view then [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) is a better choice.

View following snippet in full page mode.

```js
let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting)
      log.textContent = entry.target.textContent;
  })
});

// set elements to observe
observer.observe(one);
observer.observe(two);

down.addEventListener('click', () => two.scrollIntoView({
  behavior: "smooth",
  block: "end",
  inline: "nearest"
}));
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(150vh + 25px);
}

p {
  position: sticky;
  top: 1rem;
}

p #log {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#down {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2rem;
  right: 2rem;
  background-color: skyblue;
  padding: .3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: wheat;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50vw;
}

#one {
  background-color: rgb(250, 165, 165);
  top: 50vh;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#two {
  background-color: lime;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<span id="down"></span>
<p>Element in view: <span id="log"></span></p>
<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="two">Two</div>
```

The API is configurable you can even see how much of the element is visible.

Comment: You may want to read the question again. I asked if you could calculate the boundingClientRec position based on the matrix given. This answer has absolutely nothing to do with the question I asked.

Comment: @user3331344 in the question you've mentioned that you wish to do all this "to figure out when the element has left the screen". This is one way to do that. See the quoted text for which the answer is given.

Comment: All of these calculations need to be made before scrolling. I am starting with one matrix and ending with another and adding progress to the matrix as it is scrolling through the screen. Therefore I need to know how much the element would move when the full matrix is applied before it starts scrolling. So using intersectoinObserver would do no good because I would not be able to apply progress to the matrix if I just observed it because the progress would need to be applied to the matrix before observation which is obviously not possible.